# Alert Message is not displaying when i click h:command button in xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Alert message is not displaying when i click button. if i click a button it should show alert message as success with 3 minutes delay.

When i click the button, first it is not responding second time only it getting the value from the bean.
Why what is the reason it is not loading for the first time?

xhtml code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <script>
             var myVar;
             function myFunction() {
                 myVar = setTimeout(function(){message();},3000);
             }

             function message(){
                 myVar=setTimeout(function() {
                     if(#{mytest.count}===0) {
                         alert("Fails");
                     }
                     else {
                         alert("Success");
                     }
                },3000);
             }
        </script>

    </h:head>
    <h:body> 
        <h:form>

            <h:commandButton onclick="message();" action="#{mytest.func}"     value="click"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Managed Bean Code :

```
package com.display;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Mytest {
    private int count=0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void func(){   
        this.count=1;
        System.out.println("function called");
        System.out.println("count value is -->"+count);
    }
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling `myFunction()` function?

Comment: <h:commandButton onclick="message();" action="#{mytest.func}"     value="click"/> instead of this i use                                       <h:commandButton onclick="myFunction();" action="#{mytest.func}"     value="click"/>

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thing I wanted to point out. (This might not be an Answer but I wanted to raise some refactoring stuff which could help you resolve the issue.)

**1**. if i click a button it should show alert message as success with **3 minutes delay.**

But as per your code it is:

```
myVar = setTimeout(function(){message();},3000); //3 seconds (1000 ms = 1 seconds)
```

**2**. `myvar` is defined globally which is assigned to both function `myFunction()` and `message`. I don't see any use of `myvar` in your code.

**Edit**

Basically, your javascript code is getting invoked before going to your bean class. Check whether you can have any method `oncomplete` in your commandbutton.

Alternatively you can wrap `<f:ajax>` in your `<h:commandButton>` like,

```
<f:ajax onevent=myFunction();/>
```

Comment: If you don't require `myVar` it is better to remove it. But that's not the issue here I guess.